# Usage of same RowMapper for different result sets some columns in common

Tags: java, database, spring-jdbc

Two mappers are as below:

```
           class Apple implements RowMapper<Apple> {
            public Apple mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
              Apple a = new Apple();
              a.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
              a.setName(rs.getString("Color")); 
              a.setDesc(rs.getString("Desc"));
            }
          }

          class Apple implements RowMapper<Apple> {
            public Apple mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
              Apple a = new Apple();   
              a.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
              a.setName(rs.getString("Color"));
              a.setCost(rs.getString("Cost"));
            } 
          }
        }
```

I have two Rowmappers which returns same bean .Result set will be different in case of first cost won't be present , in second case Desc won't be present in result set. In this scenario can I use single mapper as below:

```
class Apple implements RowMapper<Apple> {

Private Boolean determine;

                public Apple mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                  Apple a = new Apple();   
                  a.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
                  a.setName(rs.getString("Color"));
                 if(determine==true){
                    a.setCost(rs.getString("Cost"));
                }else{
                a.setDesc(rs.getString("Desc"));
                  }
                } 
              }
            }
```

Passing Boolean in constructor while calling mapper. Can this be implemented, if no what would be the best way.

Note: please ignore syntax errors.

Comment: Yes you can use this method.

Comment: Yes, Implemented it and its working as expected.